# webservices access from other application

Tags: angularjs, web-services, bots

So i have a website in angularJS. 
Users can login and receive sensible data via REST webservice.

Some users leave their login+password in a post-it, in their table. (i cant change this)

In the same room there is another person, that does not have login to the system. He sees the login+pass on the post-it, and he made a 'bot' application, to login and retrieve all sensible information from webservice. (i dont know who is this person)

How can i block him, and keep my website working normally?

Thanks

Comment: One way is to talk to the users not to write their passwords anymore. Try to find out why they need to write them down (maybe you require too complex passwords - e.g. at least one capital, one digit, one special char, no repeating char etc. can be very complex to normal human beings). Then reset all the passwords. Anyway, they should be forced by security policy not to let passwords around.

Comment: Users choose their password, and can change it. They just write it. Really cant control that. So i would like to block that application. how?